# hdinsight actionscript install spark 1.2

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

Does anyone know how to create an actionscript for hdisights? I am using the actoinscript for installing spark 1.0.2 now, but want spark 1.2.x on the cluster to get more hive support. I have read the [Script Action Development with HDInsight](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-script-actions/) when I tried creating a spark cluster with 1.2 by modifying the actionscript provide by Microsoft. After doing so I was getting an error that spark does not understand the file url 'wasb://' and that it needs to be in the format 'hdfs://'. In the article it talks about [Configure the custom components to use WASB](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-script-actions/#bPS6) and it says:

```
The custom components that you install on the cluster nodes might have a 
default configuration to use HDFS storage. You should change the 
configuration to use Azure Storage Blob (WASB) instead. On a cluster 
re-image, the HDFS file system gets formatted and you would lose any data 
that is stored there. Using WASB instead ensures that your data will be 
retained.
```

This to me seems be talking to the error that I was getting. Does anyone know how to compile spark with support for (WASB) or how to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Well Microsoft added "support" for Apache Spark 1.2 Yesterday it looks like. If you use the new version of HDInsight 3.2 and use this [new action script](https://hdiconfigactions.blob.core.windows.net/sparkconfigactionv03/spark-installer-v03.ps1) it looks to install 1.2 for you. I am testing it out now!

Comment: They just deleted that action script you mention. I checked for it myself one day ago and it was available. Unfortunately, it seems *Microsoft* just removed the script some hours ago, as it is not available at this precise moment.

Comment: It seems they have re-enabled the script, they were probably having some issues with the previous version and that's why they deleted it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following powershell - it worked fine for me. You may need to update your azure powershell library first.

```
New-AzureHDInsightClusterConfig -ClusterSizeInNodes $NumClusterNodes -HeadNodeVMSize $VmSize |
Set-AzureHDInsightDefaultStorage -StorageAccountName $DefaultStorageAccountFqdn -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey -StorageContainerName $hadoopContainer |
Add-AzureHDInsightScriptAction -Name "Install Spark" -ClusterRoleCollection HeadNode -Uri https://hdiconfigactions.blob.core.windows.net/sparkconfigactionv02/spark-installer-v02.ps1 |
New-AzureHDInsightCluster -Credential $HdInsightCreds -Name $clusterName -Location $MyClusterLocation -Version $MyClusterVersion
```

Comment: this is not want I am aksing, that code will will install spark, yes, but it installs version 1.0.2 and I want a script that will install 1.2.x. I have been tring to make a new script that does it and i have made one that does but it does not work, when you start the installed spark code on yard it errors about not knowing what wasb:// is